# Use Spectron or selenium test electron based application, start Electron from cmd need pass parameter, how to pass parameters?

Tags: selenium, automation, electron, spectron

I have electron based application need to automate, but start exe need to pass parameter, how to pass parameters when use spectron or selenium to do the automation?

Here is the cmd to start Electron:

```
Electron.exe --manifest  https://hostname/quantum/configs/openfin/manfest-uat.json
```

---

My code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers/chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\xxx\\xx\\lf2v0\\UAT1\\e2o\\Electron.exe");
options.addArguments("--app=" + "C:\\xx\\xx\\lf2v0\\UAT1\\e2o");
options.addArguments("--manifest=" + "https://xxx/quantum/configs/openfin/manifest-uat.json");
options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
Thread.sleep(5000);
Set<String> windowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
```

here is the error
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can define your electron app and you can send Argument while you are initializing it like following:

`argPath` = path of your application executable

`binaryPath` = path of electron binary

```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "ChromeDriverPath");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setBinary(binaryPath);
    options.addArguments("--app=" + argPath);
    options.addArguments("--manifest=" + "https://hostname/quantum/configs/openfin/manfest-uat.json");
    options.setCapability("chromeOptions", options);
    options.setCapability("browserName", "chrome");

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Hi Ayhan, really thanks for your quick response, but still cannot start app, here is my code, could you please help  check my issue?

Comment: @yeqingwu options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage"); add this line to your code.

Comment: Still not work, does the chromedriver.exe version have additional requirement?

Comment: @yeqingwu What if you try it like following options.addArguments("manifest=https://hostname/quantum/configs/openfin/manfest-uat.json");